# "List-style : none" and "display : inline block"

Tags: html, css, html-lists, navbar, display

Is it okay if I don't use "list-style: none" because while making horizontal nav-bar, setting " display: inline-block" , bullet itself disappear. If No , why?

**HTML:**

```
        <nav>
            <ul class="horizontal-list">
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#skill">Skills</a></li>
                <li><a href="#experience">Experience</a></li>
                <li><a href="#Education">Education</a></li>
                <li><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
                <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
```

**CSS:**

```
nav li{
    /* list-style:none;  Why should i use this in this case?*/
    margin:15px 15px;
    color: white;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the attributes you choose are not affecting anything visually, the next steps would be to think of semantics and accessibility.

Apparently, Safari has a problem with [list-style:none](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/list-style#accessibility_concerns). They will not be added to the accessibility tree and this can cause problems when reading content using screen readers.
This is what the link suggests as a workaround to this issue.

```
ul {
  list-style: none;
}

ul li::before {
  content: "\200B";
}
```